# Use of resistance and capacitor in filter

Tags: low-pass, high-pass-filter

In the band pass circuit what is the role of resistance and capacitors?
How do there arrangements don't allow some specific frequencies?

[band pass filter circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aouV8.jpg)

Comment: What are you asking, more specifically? The only way I can think to answer this question is to say "To filter the signal.", which I don't think is the explanation you're seeking.

Comment: I want to know about the use of resistance and capacitor in the circuit

Comment: Without more information on what specific details you want, all I can tell you is that they are used to filter the signal. There are plenty of questions already asked and answered on here about filters; perhaps you should try searching those?

Comment: This is too broad, we'd need to give you a few lectures on signal theory

Comment: Draw your circuit there are lots of different bandpass filters and I don't we can provide a specific answer without seeing your circuit. Also at a minimum show circuit references.  Values too if you have them. Apart from that it may be useful to think about potential divider circuits while realising the impedance of a capacitor is frequency dependant.

Comment: In filter circuit what is the role of resistance and capacitor ? How their combination don't allow high frequency signals in low pass filter and low frequency signals in high pass filter?

Comment: The purpose of using the resistor and capacitor is to make a filter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your question is not specific,I will try to give you a good explanation.
The role of a capacitor is to work as a frequency dependent impedance.For simplicity ,not exactly correct, You can think of it as a frequency varying resistor.

The impedance of the capacitor decreases as the frequency increases so at high frequency signals the capacitor has low impedance.

Since in such a filter circuit we are interested in the output voltage and with just a single impedance the voltage across it(capacitor) will be the same as the input voltage.Only current changes as the impedance changes.

We know that if we connect two resistors in series a voltage divider is created and the voltage across any one of the two resistors is directly proportional to the ratio of that resistor to the total resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff2ozk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now,let us take the voltage across R2 to be our output voltage.For this simple circuit the output voltage is just one-half of the 1V(input) or 0.5V

As we increase the value of R2 the output voltage increases proportionally and if we let R2 to be very large compared to R1,say 10 times larger,the output voltage now is about the same value as the input or apprx. 1V

And if we go the other direction and let R2 be very small in comparison to R1
,May be 10 times less, the output voltage will be a negligible portion of the input or just 0V.

In conclusion,As we vary R2 the output voltage changes and we can apply the same analysis technique if we replace R2 with a capacitor and let the source voltage be sinusoidal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5cXZn.png)</sup>

To be able to analyse this circuit you have to replace the capacitor with an equivalent impedance called Xc.and it can be found as follows

Xc = 1/(2*pi*f*C) and is measured in ohms

for this circuit if we substitute f = 1000Hz and C = 10^-6 f then Xc = 160 ohms

This impedance will form a voltage divider with R1.The same way R2 did before .But now the impedance varies with frequency

If f is increased to 100KHz so Xc will be 1.6 ohms which is negligible compared to the 100 ohms connected in series with it and for all practical purposes you can assume that the output voltage(voltage between the capacitor terminals) is just 0V.

And for low values of f may be 100Hz or less the impedance of the capacitor will be in kohms and it will drop almost all the input voltage.

From this simple analysis it could be easily figured out that this circuit is a low pass filter.

Answer (score 2):

The arrangement of the capacitor and the resistor tell you what kind of filter you have in front of you:

[image]

In this first case, the capacitor "blocks" all DC frequencies, letting only higher frequency components through.

[image]

This second example is a low-pass filter. The capactir presents towards the high frequency components a lower impedance than the resistor, thus they will flow towards ground, while the low frequency components will see less impedance from the resistor, continuing its path.

Answer (score 1):

In case radiohead's answer was not what you expected, I'll give a more generalised explanation.

To filter a signal for frequencies you must decide whether to let pass a big part of a signal or or only a small (big and small part means basically a high or low amplitude at the output of your filter circuit) depending on its change in time. Time is the keyword here. As a signal changes in time more *frequently* than another you want to treat it differently.

To do that, you need something in your circuit which has a memory. Without any memory, your circuit cannot *know*, if a signal has a higher or a lower freqency compared to another.

Basically there are two types of components, you can easily buy and which have a memory. Capacitors and inductors. You could use both, but inductors have many drawbacks most important their size and susceptibility to magnetic fields from outside the circuit.

So you go and use a capacitor to memorize the past of a signal to make a *comparison* to the current state possible. Different combinations of resistors and capacitors enable a circuit to prefer the transmission of low, intermediate and high frequencies.